# Visual Studio 2010 : Error when executing the C# Project after code-analyzing with ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I opened my Visual Studio solution, then used ReSharper for code-analysis.
Then, renamed **ID** to **Id** as :
[image]

Then, I ran the code by pressing **F5** and then the following dialog box appears :
[image]

On clicking **No**, following errors are dislayed:
[image]

Now, if I undo everything using **Ctrl+Z**, then also the same errors occurs.

The code works fine before using ReSharper and it also works fine after restarting the Visual Studio.

How to get rid of these errors?

I am using **ReSharperSetup.8.2.0.2160**

Comment: please try to clean the project...

Comment: does it happen only with ID variable or with everything? Maybe it's edityng others wrong ID occurences

Comment: @faby it happen with other variables as well

Comment: @ChristianSauer I am not able to find the clean project option.
Under the "Build" menu, the only options available are build and publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Clean** option was not visible in my Visual Studio, I tried **Build -> Build Solution** and the job done.

**EDIT 1:**
Finally, found the **Clean Solution** option. It will also work. Thanks to @Christian Sauer for this suggestion.

[image]

Comment: That was the option I wanted you to try :)

Comment: @ I am new to all these things and I thought this option will be available under "Build" menu :)
BTW thanks :)